# inequality For the nonsingular upper triangular

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a nonsingular upper triangular matrix $U$.
Show that: $$\|U^{-1}\|_{\infty}≥\frac{1}{\min_{i}|u_{ii}|}.$$

I know $U^{-1}$ is a upper trianguler matrix that the diagonal
elements of $U^{-1}$ are the reciprocals of the diagonal elements of $U$.
On the other hand,$\|U^{-1}\|_{\infty}$=$max\sum_{j=0}^n|a_{ij}|$.

I do not know how to convert the minimum...

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track. All you need to show is that $\min_i|u_{ii}|\cdot||U^{-1}||_{\infty} \geq 1$. This inequality is trivially true- just consider the diagonal entries of the matrix $\min_i|u_{ii}|U^{-1}$